# What approaches are there for applying RNNs when there is only a single long sequence?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, model

Most  of the applications of RNNs I see are applied to multiple short  sequences, such as sentences or market prediction. Each sentence or  stock is one observation.

But what if you only have a single sequence? For example, 10 years of weather information from different types of sensors?

I read this post [What is a feasible sequence length for an RNN to model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158834/what-is-a-feasible-sequence-length-for-an-rnn-to-model) which says long sequences aren't a problem, but in my case I only have *one* sequence. I don't know if it makes any sense to try to feed a single sequence into an RNN, for example how would batch updates work?

Setting `stateful=True` (as described at http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/) seems relevant here, but again, since there's only one sequence, it doesn't exactly make sense immediately.

I  know that one option is to chop up the time series into multiple small  windows and take each window as a separate sequence. But this can  disrupt patterns that happen over very long periods of time. Are there  any other approaches?

Comment: *weather information from different types of sensors*  sounds like multiple sequences---anyhow, with such small data you are probably better off with more traditional time series models.